# How do have icons in a listview on Desktop

Tags: icons

For Windows user's there is a tweak to make your desktop icons in a list view as you can see here:
http://www.howtogeek.com/?post_type=post&p=959

Icons normally on Desktop:

[image]

Icons in a listview:

[image]

I've managed to have icons in a listview on Macbook as well, which has this option as in-built functionality.

How can I achieve the same functionality on Ubuntu(Unity)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright, answer is finally here. You have to change line or two in nautilus source and than recompile the source...

**Text besides icons on Ubuntu Desktop**

Text besides icons on Ubuntu Desktop

1-$ mkdir /home/nautilus-source & cd /home/nautilus-source

2-$ apt-get source nautilus #in my case it downloaded source for nautilus-3.4.2

3-$ sudo apt-get install fakeroot build-essential dpkg-dev

4-$ sudo apt-get build-dep nautilus

5-$ cd /home/nautilus-source/nautilus-3.4.2/

6-$ vim src/nautilus-desktop-icon-view.c

7-$ /NAUTILUS_TYPE_DESKTOP_ICON_VIEW

Change from:

g_object_new (NAUTILUS_TYPE_DESKTOP_ICON_VIEW, "window-slot", slot, "supports-zooming", **FALSE**, "supports-auto-layout", FALSE, "supports-scaling", TRUE,"supports-keep-aligned", TRUE, "supports-labels-beside-icons", **FALSE**, NULL);

to:

g_object_new (NAUTILUS_TYPE_DESKTOP_ICON_VIEW, "window-slot", slot, "supports-zooming", **TRUE**, "supports-auto-layout", FALSE, "supports-scaling", TRUE,"supports-keep-aligned", TRUE, "supports-labels-beside-icons", **TRUE**, NULL);

Line numbers in in src/nautilus-desktop-icon-view.c > 785-792

8-$ dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -us -uc -nc -b

9-$ sudo dpkg -i ../nautilus_3.4.2-0ubuntu4_i386.deb

10-$ killall nautilus

11- Open your home folder from launcher -

12- Edit > Preferences > Views > Check Text Besides Icons

ps. also now Ctrl+Scroll - will zoom in zoom out desktop icons

ps2. you can also change location of launcher # edit src/nautilus-places-sidebar.c

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm on the process of trying it out. Check the link on the bottom of the page here:

http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-841696.html

Good luck! :)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do it by clicking the desktop, and then selecting "view>list" in the global menu bar ;)